# Disabling anonymous access in List using CSOM

Tags: 2013, csom, anonymous-authentication, inheritance

I have a site collection which is set to be anonymous (Entire Website). I am trying to create a SharePoint List and break inheritance without copying RoleAssignments from parent and assigning only the Owner group access to the list. All works fine except the the list still have Anonymous access enabled in it. [image]
Is there any way to disable the anonymous access on the list through CSOM?